# Having problems with an email-form on html

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I been having problems with coding an email-form on my site.
I have my html index page and the php code its on other document.

This is my Html:

```
<form class="customform" method="post"action="form-to-email.php">
<div class="Email"><input name="" placeholder="Your e-mail" 
title="Email" type="text" /></div>
<div class="Name"><input name="" placeholder="Your name" 
title="Name" type="text" /></div>
<div class="Message"><textarea placeholder="Your message" name="" 
rows="5"></textarea></div>
<div class="s-12 m-12 l-4"><button class="color-btn" 
type="submit" value="Send Form" >Submit Button</button> </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Message = $_POST['Message'];
?>

<?php
$email_from = 'info@alvaconsultorias.com';
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user 
$name.\n". "Here is the message:\n $message"
?>

<?php

  $to = "info@alvaconsultorias.com";
  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

 ?>
```

My page hasn't been uploaded yet, i haven been just previewing it on chrome. I don't know if that maybe an issue.

Thanks, any help would be grateful.

Comment: change `button` with `input type="submit"`

Comment: don't forget to add `names` to the first and second `inputs` and `textarea` too

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML inputs need to have names

```
<form class="customform" method="post"action="form-to-email.php">
<div class="Email">
<input name="Email" placeholder="Your e-mail" title="Email" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="Name">
<input name="Name" placeholder="Your name" title="Name" type="text" />
</div>

<div class="Message">
<textarea placeholder="Your message" name="Message" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="s-12 m-12 l-4">
<input type="submit" class="color-btn" name="submit" value="Submit Button" >
</div>
</form>
```

And it's nice to add a verification to your PHP code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Message = $_POST['Message'];

$email_from = 'info@alvaconsultorias.com';
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user 
$name.\n". "Here is the message:\n $message"

$to = "info@alvaconsultorias.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}
?>
```

I hope that can help you

Comment: Thanks so much, i would try this

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the pages through a Web server like Apache or nginx? Nothing will happen if you are just viewing them as standalone files. You may need to download/install WAMP (Windows) or MAMP (MacOS) first.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code. The first page needs to have names defined for each input:

```
<form class="customform" method="post"action="p.php">
<div class="Email">
    <input name="Email" placeholder="Your e-mail" title="Email" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="Name">
    <input name="Name" placeholder="Your name" title="Name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="Message">
    <textarea placeholder="Your message" name="Message" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="s-12 m-12 l-4">
    <button class="color-btn" type="submit" value="Send Form" >Submit Button</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Then secondly, your PHP script was referencing variables that had typos in them. Here's what you'd probably want it to look like:

```
<?php
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Message = $_POST['Message'];

$email_from = 'info@alvaconsultorias.com';
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $Name.\n".
  "Here is the message:\n $Message";

$to = "info@alvaconsultorias.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $Email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
?>
```